# Manage toolbar's navigation and back button from fragment to fragment in android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

All of my fragments are controlled through `ActionBarActivity` (**mainActivity**), inside **mainActivity** a `DrawerLayout` is implemented and all the child fragments are pushed through drawerLayout's list item click. The problem that I'm facing is after pushing a fragment through drawerLayout I want to change the drawer icon into back icon of `ToolBar` so that user can navigate to previous fragment and to handle the callback of android.R.id.home either inside the same fragment or inside the **mainActivity**.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have add `Fragment` to back stack and add **listener**  in fragment manager like this

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // show back button
                    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            onBackPressed();
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    //show hamburger
                    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
                    toggle.syncState();
                    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Я искал это очень долго!!! Спасибо огромное!!!   // I looked for it very long!!! Thanks a lot!!!